# C++ template class, template member friend function matching rules

Tags: c++, type-traits, friend-function, template-function

I have a templated class with a templated friend function declaration that is not having its signature matched when stated in a more direct, but seemingly equivalent, expression:

[link to example on online compiler](https://godbolt.org/g/8PJ9sX)

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Sig> class Base;
template <typename R, typename ... Args> class Base<R(Args...)> { };
template <typename Sig, typename T> class Derived;
template <typename Sig> struct remove_membership;

template <typename T, typename R, typename ... Args>
class Derived<R(Args...), T> : public Base<R(Args...)> {
  static void bar() { }

  // XXX: why are these two not equivalent, and only the 1st version successful?
  template <typename T2>
  friend auto foo(T2 const &) -> Base<typename
    remove_membership<decltype(&std::remove_reference_t<T2>::operator())>::type> *;
  template <typename T2>
  friend auto foo(T2 const &) -> Base<R(Args...)> *;
};

template <typename F, typename R, typename ... Args>
struct remove_membership<R (F::*)(Args...) const> {
  using type = R(Args...);
};

template <typename T>
auto foo(T const &) -> Base<typename 
remove_membership<decltype(&std::remove_reference_t<T>::operator())>::type> * 
{
  using base_param_t = typename remove_membership<
    decltype(&std::remove_reference_t<T>::operator())>::type;
  Derived<base_param_t, T>::bar();
  return nullptr;
}

int main(int, char **) { foo([](){}); } // XXX blows up if verbose friend decl. removed.
```

Inside member definitions of `Derived<R(Args...), T>` (for example, in the body of `bar()`), the types match, adding to my confusion:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<Base<R(Args...)>, Base<typename  
  remove_membership<decltype(&std::remove_reference_t<T>::operator())>::type>>::value,
  "signature mismatch");
```

Are there rules around template class template member function (and friend function) delarations and instantiations that make these preceding declarations distinct in some or all circumstances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <typename T2>
void foo(T2 const &)

template <typename T2>
auto foo(T2 const &)
-> std::enable_if_t<some_traits<T2>::value>;
```

Are 2 different overloads. Even if both return `void` (when valid).
2nd overload uses SFINAE.

(and yes, template functions can differ only by return type contrary to regular functions).

Your version is not identical but similar (`&std::remove_reference_t<T>::operator()` should be valid)

You can use the simpler template friend function:

```
template <typename T, typename R, typename ... Args>
class Derived<R(Args...), T> : public Base<R(Args...)> {
  static void bar() { }

  template <typename T2>
  friend auto foo(T2 const &) -> Base<R(Args...)>*;
};

template <typename T>
auto foo(T const &) -> Base<void()>* // friend with Derived<void(), U>
{
  using base_param_t = typename remove_membership<
    decltype(&std::remove_reference_t<T>::operator())>::type;
  Derived<base_param_t, T>::bar();
  return nullptr;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd4c9e6921d5b7fb)

but you have then to implement different version of the template `foo`.

Comment: I unfortunately need to leave the function `Sig` parameter generic and to have `template <typename T> auto foo(T const &) -> ...` be available for any signature, not just specializations on an as-needed basis. I appreciate your point above about the SFINAE nuace though.

Comment: You can shorten your current code with alias: `template <typename T> using FooReturnType = Base<typename 
remove_membership<decltype(&std::remove_reference_t<T>::operator())>::type> *;` and then `template <typename T>
auto foo(T const &) -> FooReturnType<T>`.

Comment: I had wanted to avoid leaving another helper template at namespace scope, but this had been my fallback plan.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be reduced to:

```
template<class T>
struct identity {
    using type=T;
};

class X {
    int bar();
public:
    template<class T>
    friend T foo();
};

template<class T>
typename identity<T>::type foo() { return X{}.bar(); }

int main() {
    foo<int>(); // error: bar is a private member of X
}
```

Even though *we* know `identity<T>::type` is always `T`, the compiler doesn't know that and would be wrong to assume so. There could be a specialization of `identity<T>` somewhere later in the code that resolves to some type other than `T`.

Therefore when the compiler sees the second declaration of `foo` it won't assume that it is the same friend `foo` declared before.

Comment: So is the friend access check is being done in the calling (attempted) friended template function body at some phase before actual instantiation? Using `template <class T> friend auto foo();` plus `template <class T> auto foo() { return X{}.bar(); }` works for you code, but the analogous transformation to mine above does not seem to.